# Convert multiple images to png with Adam7 interlacing

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any application in Ubuntu which can convert multiple images to png with Adam7 interlacing like in Gimp

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Image Magic first

   `sudo apt-get -y install imagemagick`
2. use the convert command in your image directory like this

   `convert -interlace PNG *.jpg images.png`

Hint: The best way to figure this out is to make a copy of your image directory and try it more than ones.

More information about imagemagick could be found at: [Image Magic.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but I don't get good quality like in Gimp, am I missing some options

Comment: you could specify more options with the command line option switches located  [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php#options)


If you want to maximize quality use --compress Loosless

Comment: Thank you it works, but I found better solution for me

Answer (score 1):

I found really good plugin which solved my problem. It is called Bimp and it basically allows you to use all Gimp effects and plugins but for multiple images. You can download it from here: http://www.alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/

Answer (score 1):

## [David's Batch Processor](http://members.ozemail.com.au/%7Ehodsond/dbp.html) - Plug-in

You can use this plug-in to do batch jobs in gimp. To install run the following in terminal (this will also install a lot of other useful plug-ins)

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

Now you can do the following after it installed and you restarted gimp

1. From the menu choose Filters -> Batch -> Batch Process...
2. Click Add Files and add the files and click close when done
3. Go to the Output tab and change format to png and set options as needed(interlacing option appears here)
4. Go to Rename tab and change as needed (changing the output/save directory to something else can be done by clicking Select Dir which can help to keep the originals separate from the edits)
5. Click Test at the bottom to test output for a single file and if all seems OK then click Start and wait for it to finish